# Sunspot: find all events in a country, or state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, geolocation, sunspot

The title is not clear so let me explain:

In my apps, I have events. They are geolocated: I store the latitude and longitude.
My problem is that, when users search for events, they type things like: `kansas`, `montreal` etc.
So when I locate `kansas` (using geocoder), I get its "center", and so when I ask sunspot for the events "near" this location, I only get the ones close to the center of the location. It's even worse if they type `france` or `australia`.

I was wondering if you knew about a good way to handle that.

My only idea right now is to also store the `country`, `state` etc of the location of the event when it's saved (I can get the normalized address from google), and then do a text search of what they entered in the location field...

But there is problem about that approach :(
In solr, it's impossible to do the following:

```
any_of do
    with(:coordinates).near(coord[0], coord[1], :precision => 3)
    keywords where
end
```

because `near` can't be nested. [See here.](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-sunspot/browse_thread/thread/fab304f94ed55b6a)

Did they make changes in sunspot 1.3 to allow that?

Do you see any other solution? I might even accept changing from solr to another search platform like elastic search but I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to ElasticSearch, and I absolutely love it. It's so much better for geolocation search... I still have some problems with facets, but overall I would recommend ES over sunspot for someone starting a new app.